# One hot encoding/dummy on date

Tags: python, pandas

I have this pandas data frame

```
user     join_date      session
A        2018-09-20     2019-10-20
B        2018-01-01     2019-10-20
B        2018-01-01     2019-10-21
...
```

I want to transform it to this

```
user     join_date      2019-10-20     2019-10-21    ...   n
A        2018-09-20     1              0             ...   0
B        2018-01-01     1              1             ...   0
...
```

The user will be grouped per user and I have sorted the session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
a = pd.crosstab(df.user, df.session).reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
df.merge(a , on='user').drop('session', axis=1).drop_duplicates()
```

**Output**

```
  user  join_date   2019-10-20  2019-10-21
0   A   2018-09-20           1           0
1   B   2018-01-01           1           1
```

Comment: it worked on the example that you have put. Can you try on the example you have out & then try on the actual data that you may have? Also, do you get an error?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to use is the function [pd.get_dummies()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html), as follows:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({"user": ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'session': ['2019-10-20', '2019-10-20', '2018-10-21']})
    pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['session'])
```

producing an output

```
    Out[137]: 
      user  session_2018-10-21  session_2019-10-20
    0    A                   0                   1
    1    B                   0                   1
    2    C                   1                   0
```

Comment: What if there is two B?